# IBOutlet UILabel not updating after delegate call

Tags: ios, uilabel, iboutlet

**Screencast:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwehDwITEyI

This is really bizarre. The problem is to do with a label outlet sitting in a custom-designed table cell. That cell is of my CustomCell class. (actually called RA_FormCell if you watch the screencast).

CustomCell.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dayOutlet;
-(void)controller:(id<CustomCellDelegate>)controller didUpdateDay:(NSString *)theDay;
```

CustomCell.m

```
// Method is called by a view controller
// (which is itself a delegate of the CustomCell class,
// hence the identifier you see below)

-(void)controller:(id<CustomCellDelegate>)controller didUpdateDay:(NSString *)theDay;
{
    NSLog(@"Method called") // confirms to me that method is called
    self.dayOutlet.text = @"Goodmorning";
    NSLog(@"%@", self.dayOutlet.text); // displays (null)
}
```

That final log does actually appear, so the method is definitely being called. I have discounted the following:

1. `self.dayOutlet.text` is not written to elsewhere by any other method in the project
2. dayOutlet is connected to the label in the storyboard (and the label is not connected to anything else)
3. The label is not hidden underneath some accidental static label on the storyboard
4. The cell attributes on the storyboard include its class as `CustomCell`
5. No warnings or alerts in Xcode (I have been careful to avoid any circular imports)

Comment: Is there a chance that 'didUpdateDay' is called not on the main thread ?

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion but no: http://postimg.org/image/c2ndiic4j/

Comment: Where's your evidence that the `self.dayOutlet` link is working? What happens if you log just that?

Comment: I agree, based on your description, `self.dayOutlet` is nil - you should check this with the debugger

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems there is a structural error in this.
As far as i know or seem to understand, updating outlets or pretty much anything that has to do with outlet, the logic itself must be written in the view controller of that element.

Comment: @Tommy - if I assign self.dayOutlet.text in another method, it updates fine

Comment: @LightYagami - interesting theory (do you have any references?), although I tried testing this theory with another example

Comment: I'll post a screencast to demonstrate. Also notifying @Paulw11

Comment: Screencast added! Hope it clarifies the issue, for anyone with the patience :-)

Comment: I couldn't exactly follow what was going on because of all the delegate stuff, but my suspicion is that the final RA_FormCell instance (the one that is printing null) isn't the same one that started the whole thing.  You should set a breakpoint in your stepper handler and single-step into the whole sequence - check the value of "self" as you go from the cell and back to the cell object to make sure you are dealing with the right instance

Comment: Paul I think you are right! They are different instances. The delegate is getting overwritten multiple times because it's in cellForRowAtIndexPath. So I'm actually delegating to the last row on the table, not the first. Dang, I wonder if this means I actually need to set up multiple delegates (one for each instance). Better yet, if only there was a way to establish RA_ShoutForm at a data source for RA_FormCell. I googled but can't figure out if there's a way to implement custom DataSource relationships

Comment: The whole bi-directional delegation thing is a bit icky (technical term). Your `didChangeDay1` method already has a reference to the cell - so just invoke `[customCell didUpdateDay];` or even just update the `dayOutlet` directly from `didChangeDay1`

Comment: Of course! Brilliant. So I guess there's hardly ever a reason to have a two-way delegate, because you can just pass 'self' into any method that you want to delegate elsewhere, therefore always letting the delegate know where the message came from.

Comment: What's best - should I add the answer myself?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `controller:didUpdateDay:` message was not sent to the correct instance of the cell class.

This occurred because I had not correctly assigned this cell to be the delegate for the view controller. For anyone interested, in my screencast at 3:50, you can see that I have the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
RA_FormCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.formCellArray[indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
self.delegate = cell
```

However, this means that self.delegate got continually overwritten as the table cells were generated. As a result, my `controller:didUpdateDay` message was sent to the bottom cell of the table, and not the top one as I required.

The solution was simple - there's no need to have this second delegate at all. Instead, when the cell delegates to the view controller, it should pass `self` into the message it delegates:

```
id<CustomCellDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;

if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customCell:didChangeDay1:)])
    [strongDelegate customCell:self didChangeDay1:[sender value]];
```

Then, in the implementation of this method by the delegate, simply end it by changing the outlet directly:

```
-(void)customCell:(RA_FormCell *)customCell didChangeDay1:(double)value
    // put logic here
    customCell.dayOutlet.text = @"No problem!";
```

In general, there should rarely be a need for a two-way delegate structure. Keep it one way, from `A` to `B`, and just remember to have `A` pass `self` in any messages it sends to `B`. That way, `B` will know the object the message came from, and be able to communicate back to `A`.

Thanks to Paulw11